# Make a fixed add to cart button on mobile device

Tags: html, css

Hi this is only a css question , please help to solve this

http://flatsome.uxthemes.com/product/wicked-ss-o-neck-selected-homme/ this is the theme preview .

mobile view : How  to show make the add to cart form  full width with fixed position in footer , so user can any time see the button without scrolling page . 
i tried

```
position: fixed;
text-align: center;
```

But i don't know it is correct way . Please help .

Comment: Does it work doing it that way?

Comment: When i give position: fixed; to form element then it disappear . Please help to do this . When we taking http://www.snapdeal.com in mobile device , their product page buy now button is working very good and customer can easily see their buy now button

Comment: share the link to your online site that you're working on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell it *where* you want it fixed. Here's a simple example with an element fixed at the bottom, 20px in from the edges:

```css
html, body {margin:0;}
p {margin:20px;}

#addToCart {
  display:block;
  position:fixed;
  text-align:center;
  background:black;
  color:white;
  bottom:20px; 
  left:20px;
  right:20px;
  padding:20px;
}
```

```html
<a id="addToCart" href="#">Add to Cart</a>
<p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue.</p>
<p>Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
<p>Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet.</p>
<p>Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Donec sed odio dui. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue.</p>
<p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue.</p>
<p>Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit sit amet non magna. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
<p>Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Integer posuere erat a ante venenatis dapibus posuere velit aliquet.</p>
<p>Maecenas faucibus mollis interdum. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Donec sed odio dui. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue.</p>
```

Comment: When we taking snapdeal.com in mobile device , their product page buy now button is working very good and customer can easily see their buy now button

Comment: your code fork good , but when i apply this the form is fixed ,but it is floating around with content, and the content of other div like description are showing in the black background also  . I need to make it fix like the example site . Please help

Comment: <form class="cart" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    position:fixed;
    text-align:center;
    background:black;
    color:white;
    bottom: 0%;
    left:20px;
    right:20px;
    padding:20px;
">
    please check this

Answer (score 1):

You can make it work by doing this:

Instead of setting the position and bottom on the button element, set it on the whole form. This is from inspect element:

```
<form style="" class="cart" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.cart {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0%;
}
```

Comment: @Manik Please accept the answer if it worked for you. Thanks!